# Use regex to replace in batch

Tags: regex, batch-file

I just want add a single quotation to all the dates in a file by batch script. 
2006/04/26 20:24:26　→ '2006/04/26 20:24:26'
For some reason I have to use regex.

I tried using findstr in batch ,actually it doesn't work.
`SET "REGEX=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"`
I guess I should use powershell or vbs to do it.
But I'm not  familiar with neither powershell nor vbs,I'm a little confused by the sample codes.

Dose anyone has some clue?

Comment: `FINDSTR` literally means what the command says.  It finds a string.  It does not replace.

Comment: Please check my answer below, and let know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) `jrepl "\d{4}/\d\d/\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d" "'$&'" /f yourFile.txt /o -`  Add CALL before JREPL if you use the command within a batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't search *and replace* with `findstr` utility, it is only meant to search for some specific patterns, and its regex arsenal is quite limited.

Instead, consider a short Powershell script that uses .NET regex:

```
(gc your_file.txt) -replace '\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', "'`$&'" | sc your_file_updated.txt
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%7B4%7D%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D%2F%5Cd%7B2%7D%20%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D&i=2006%2F04%2F26%2020%3A24%3A26&r=%27%24%26%27).

**NOTE**:

- `(gc your_file.txt)` (=`(Get-Content your_file.txt)`) reads in `your_file.txt` line by line
- `-replace` runs a regex-based replacement on the contents found
- `\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` matches `{4 digits}/{2 digits}/{2 digits} {2 digits}:{2 digits}:{2 digits}` patterns
- and then `'$&'` replacement pattern replaces each match with itself (`$&`) inside single quotes
- `sc your_file_updated.txt` - (=`Set-Content your_file_updated.txt`) saves the result into `your_file_updated.txt` file.

Comment: Isn't there a `\`` too much in `"'\`$&'"`?

Comment: @Stephan Well, it is a double quotes string literal, where string interpolation is allowed. When a `$` is prepended with `\``, the `$` is treated as a literal `$` symbol. I tested this code on my machine and it does what is necessary. `\`` is an esape symbol, like ``\`` is in regex escapes for special characters.

Comment: ... and I was naive enough to believe, PowerShell has overcome Character-Escaping. (I just sniffed into Powershell yet)

Comment: Thank u so much. It seems that only powershell or vbs,swf can do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using Regex in vbscript with a batch file :

```
@echo off
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=%1"
If "%~x1" NEQ ".txt" Goto :Help
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0OutPutFile.txt"
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & Exit
::------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"
    echo strReplace = "'$&'"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::------------------------------------------------------------------
:Help
Color 0C & Mode 85,3
echo(
echo       Usage : Drag and Drop a txt file over this script:"%~nx0"  
Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & Exit
::------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank u so much.
I really like your answer ,the csript is made by the batch ,so no extra file needed.
Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote for u.